# How to handle calculated models in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

From a model called `Suggestion`, I need to calculate another model that is called `Task`.

`Task` objects doesn't need to store anything in the database since it is totally calculated using `Suggestion` fields.

An exemple would be a task of approving a suggestion using fields :

- `approver`
- `state`
- `approving_deadline`

Is their a standard way in `django` to handle this kind of models that doesn't need to store any information but are fully  calculated using other models ?

Comment: Why does it need to be a model, if it's not storing anything in the database?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's a model semantically, according to the principle ""programme to an interface not an implementation" it should somehow be treated like a model since it has the same interface as a model, for example : I need to create a ModelSerializer for that using django-rest-frameowrk but I couldn't because django can't treat it like model.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `SerializerMethodField`:

1. In your Serializer, create a field for your Task like `task = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`
2. Still, in your serializer, create a method called `get_taks(self, obj)`. `obj` is your current `Suggestion`, from which you need to calculate your task and return it as serialized data (the `Task` primary key using `task.pk`, or a serialized `Task` using `TaskSerializer(task).data`, or whatever you prefer).

ex.:

```
class SuggestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Suggestion
        fields = [
            'id', 'approver', 'state', 'approving_deadline', 
            ..., 'task'
        ]

    def get_tasks(self, obj):
        # obj is a Suggestion instance
        task = my_get_task_from_suggestion_helper(obj) 
        return task.id # or TaskSeriaizer(task).data
```

You can read more detail about SerializerMethodField on [Django REST Framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)